# OpenCV convert to jpeg slow

Tags: c++, opencv

I've a problem: If I run OpenCV my CPU is at 100%. (Intel Penthium 2x3,3GhZ)

Is there a way to get a better performance? If I use a GPU for encoding, will it be better and how could I do this with OpenCV?

Heres my code:

```
_videoCapture >> frame;

cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_8U);

param[0] = CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;

std::vector<uchar> buff;

cv::Mat clientFrame;

cv::resize(frame,clientFrame, cv::Size(CAMERA_WIDTH*((float) client.second.GetFrameSize()/100),CAMERA_HEIGHT*((float) client.second.GetFrameSize()/100)));

param[1] = client.second.GetFrameQuality();

imencode(".jpeg", clientFrame, buff, param);
```

Comment: Despite the fact that your CPU is at 100% it doesn't mean slow conversion. What about the runtime of `imencode`? What's the resolution of your images?

Comment: The resolution is 1280x720 and a quality of 50.